# What is a first order formula for $\left\vert{S}\right\vert \equiv 0 \mod 2$ in set theory?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is a first order formula for $\left\vert{S}\right\vert \equiv 0 \mod 2$ using only ZF axioms? My intuition makes me think about something like $\exists x \cdot \mathbb{P}(x) = S$, but this clearly does not work.

Edit: $S$ is known to be finite.

Comment: A good first step is to just explain it in words. Suppose I'm living in a model $V$ of ZF, and I'm looking at a set $X$. What about $X$ makes it even or not? Don't try to make this first-order just yet - just explain clearly what "being even" *means* to you.

Comment: Actually, you need to clarify what "$\equiv 0$ (mod $2$)" means for arbitrary sets; I can think of two reasonable interpretations, but they're **not equivalent** over ZF! (They are equivalent over ZFC.)

Comment: Hint: Suppose $X\subseteq S$. How can you say that the size of $X$ is *half* the size of $S$? (Sub-hint: consider $S\setminus X$.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the set $S$ is finite so that it makes sense to check for cardinality as a number.

Comment: Oh, *finite* $S$! :P Well then. My *first* comment still stands.

Comment: I guess my problem is that I don't know how to express the cardinal of a set. Following the comment from @BrianO , I should check that there exists a set $X \subset S$ such that $\vert X \vert = \vert S - X \vert$, but I'm not entirely sure on how to enforce this.

Comment: You don't need to use the *cardinality* of anything. $|A| = |B|$ means... what? Although the statement overtly talks about the cardinals of $A$ and $B$, you don't need cardinals to express an equivalent condition.

Comment: I guess that I could just say that there is a function $f : A \rightarrow B$ that is bijective. Is that what you're thinking about?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: Cool, thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's a pretty neat explanation of "evenness", right? $|S|$ is even precisely when you can partition it into two parts of the same size.

Comment: Definitely, but since it's my first time trying to work with axiomatic set theory it seems a bit strange to do it this way since I've always taken such things for granted.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of expressing that something is even: It can be written as the sum of two parts of the same size; or it can be written as the sum of $2$'s.

For finite sets the two notions are equivalent, but without the axiom of choice we cannot ensure that for infinite sets being even according to the one would mean being even according to the other (and we cannot prove that every infinite set is even, in either definition).

1. What does it mean that a set $S$ can be written as a sum of two parts of the same cardinality? It means there are $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_1\cup S_2=S$ and $S_1\cap S_2=\varnothing$, and there is a bijection from $S_1$ to $S_2$. We can express all those things with formulas in the language of set theory, but the more you want to write explicitly the uglier it gets.
2. What does it mean that a set $S$ can be written as a sum of $2$'s? It means there is a partition of $S$ where every part is exactly a pair $\{x,y\}$ with $x\neq y$. Namely, there is a set $T$ of subsets of $S$ such that:

   1. Every element of $S$ appears in exactly one element of $T$.
   2. Every element of $T$ has exactly two elements.

   Again, writing this in full formality in the language of set theory is tantamount to self-inflicted wounds. But it can be done, if you do it slowly and carefully it's a reasonable exercise for the first week of the semester that explains why we usually prove that we can write something, rather than writing it explicitly.